# BitBlt drawing black squares (Windows 7)

Tags: c, winapi, gdi, bitblt

I am creating a desktop virtualization capture driver. Basically, the driver opens a virtualized desktop and captures the screen into a bitmap buffer and sends it to the client which then gets drawn onto their screen (`GetDIBits`/`SetDIBits`).

The problem is, the problem is with `PrintWindow` in Windows 7. In Windows 8.1+ there was an extra flag added to this function `PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT` which draws the entire desktop in one go, however in Windows 7 this flag doesn't exist.

My question is, how can I properly emulate this flags behaviour in Windows 7 such that all windows are drawn properly. For example, without this flag, when the host machine opens Chrome in their virtualized desktop, the `PrintWindow` call fails since Chrome is rendered with Aura and `PrintWindow` isn't built to handle this functionality, hence chrome is drawn with a black square in the middle:

[image]

Comment: You can copy the whole desktop screen, it will copy whatever is on the screen. If you call `GetDC(somewindow)` it will lead to this problem, there is no way around it as far as I know.

Comment: Please edit the question and make [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40367360/4603670)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani "*it will copy whatever is on the screen*" - not everything, for instance windows protected by [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340.aspx) will not be copied.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's true. I don't think Chrome uses `SetWindowDisplayAffinity`, at least not by default. It might not be the problem here.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test indicates the capturing the correct area of the screen produces correct results. Code like this:

```
memDC.BitBlt(0, 0, src_rect.Width(), src_rect.Height(), 
             &screen, 
             src_rect.TopLeft().x, src_rect.TopLeft().y, 
             SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
```

...was adequate to capture a picture of your question being displayed in Chrome:

[image]

`CAPTUREBLT` is recommended, but doesn't seem to be truly necessary for this particular case. This code is using MFC's wrapper around BitBlt, but that shouldn't change anything significant compared to calling `BitBlt` directly.

Comment: Capturing the window itself is not a problem. In my question I stated that I am trying to capture chrome from a virtualized desktop, meaning I have it running in another desktop station (`CreateDesktopA`/`OpenDesktopA`). It is not visible in the current desktop session so I am forced to send a `WM_PAINT` message (`PrintWindow`) to it before drawing, but since Chrome uses `DirectComposition` it won't register with the `WM_PAINT` message. I managed to get around this by disabling direct composition with a flag, but I am looking for a native solution.